# vertical-align issue

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to get a vertical-align to work on a div whose display is table-cell.

See http://jsfiddle.net/midnitesonnet/Rwahk/ for html/css.

I can't seem get the  to display vertically align to the bottom. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `display:table-cell` & `position:absolute` which create a problem. Just remove your **.title** DIV `height`.

```
#whats_available .title {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center !important;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Rwahk/5/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Rwahk/7/ works as you wanted...

The changes made were to add `display: table;` to the `#whats_available > div` and to change the `.title` to `position: relative;`

Answer (score 0):

You should change the height of the inner div to something like 30px instead of 100%
http://jsfiddle.net/Rwahk/4/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use dimensions attributes in pure html (the only exception could be image but it's still a bad idea).

Comment: Actually, adding dimension attributes to images is a good idea to speed up page loading.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this small jQuery function which might comes in handy to you or to other readers.

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
}
```

use:

```
$(selector).center();
```

Enjoy and have a great day :)